# Does measuring a photons position violate the uncertainty relation?

Tags: velocity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

The velocity of a photon has an exact value: the speed of light. We don't have to make a measurement of the photon's velocity to know its velocity. So if we measure the photon's position (thereby destroying the photon, although the presence of the photon can also be detected without destroying it; see [this](https://www.nature.com/news/photons-detected-without-being-destroyed-1.14179) article, which prompted this question) with very high accuracy, will the uncertainty principle be circumvented?

Or does one have to make a wavelength (energy) measurement on the photon too, in contrast to massive particles which have fixed values of the mass and so only their velocity has to be measured?

Answer (score 2):

Constant speed is not constant velocity or constant momentum. Heisenberg's uncertainty principle (in position-momentum form) applies to the vector momentum, not just its known absolute value. So if you can determine a photon's position very precisely, at a very precise instant in time, then you know very little about which direction it's moving.

Comment: But position operators commute. Can't we measure the position in every direction at once?

Comment: Maybe. But position or speed, which are you measuring?

Comment: Ah, it's clear now. It's the position that can be measured exactly. The direction of the velocity will indeed be completely uncertain then. So the HUR applies to the position and direction of the speed (which is fixed, namely c)?